# How to enable and disabled full screen option in CrossMediaManager

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm showing HLS Content on CrossMediaManager player. But on Android player there is no full screen option available, is there a way to enable it?

[image]

For iOS I want to disable the full screen option temporarily until they fix the bug mentioned here: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/issues/629

[image]

Comment: Yes, it can certainly be added. I found this tutorial, however, I am still looking how to convert it to Xamarin.Forms: https://medium.com/@danyalstd/adding-a-fullscreen-button-to-exoplayer-87f685279cae give it a try.